# Can't auto-resize layout & image added to it when resizing window, why? How to limit draggable image to layout area? All in Kivy

Tags: kivy

The dream goal is to make a chessboard where I can mouse-drag pieces and have the whole board with pieces auto-resize when the app window is user-resized manually with the mouse.

I don't get why the FloatLayout is not resizing & why the Image isn't either. Additionally, I'd like to know if there's a built-in way to limit movement of the image so it doesn't exceed layout boundaries.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.write()

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class DraggableArea(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DraggableArea, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=(200, 200),
                                  pos=(300, 200))
            self.add_widget(MoveableImage(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/WhiteQueen.png", pos=(350, 250), ))


class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drag_timeout = 10000000
        self.drag_distance = 0
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]
        self.size_hint = (self.image_ratio, 1)
        self.keep_ratio = True
        self.allow_stretch = True

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.drag_rectangle = [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]


class egGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        c = DraggableArea()
        print("layout size = ", c.size)
        print("layout position = ", c.pos)
        return c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    egGameApp().run()
```

Comment: have you tried changing the `size=(200, 200)` part of your `Rectangle` object at `self.rect` to `size_hint=(1, 1)`?

Comment: Ok, I changed the size_hint (as you stated) of the DraggableArea class, not the 'self.rect=' line, and I achieved auto-resizing! Thank you! How easy! ----Is there any easy way to limit the draggable area of the image to just the layout dimensions?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, since I usually overthink too much, but no, I don't think there's any easy way to achieve such thing. Though you can try defining the `on_touch_move` method of your `MoveableImage` class and make it so that if the user drags the image so that it goes out of the draggable area, it will change the coords of your image back to the border of your layout. Though this may work, I'm not really sure about it, since the kivy documentation about `DragBehavior` isn't that helpful, but it's worth a try